# How to maintain GridView and ListView over the click of each tabbed page

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

We are developing an iOS shopping cart application in c#, visual studio 2017 for xamarin. Here we are using listview and gridview for displaying items using dynamic tabbed pages in the content page from rest api, "Default we show on listview" if we click on gridview button then items are shown on the gridview. All tab pages navigate to the same content page.

How do I maintain gridview and listview over the click of each tabbed page? Now when we select gridview in the default content page and click on next child tab page then item must be shown on gridview because previous page selected on grid but items are showing in listview.

```
//My tabbed page created from rest api below
protected async override void OnAppearing() {
  base.OnAppearing();
  var objcata = await App.TodoManager.GetEmployeeTasksAsync(Convert.ToString(Application.Current.Properties["LoginName"]));
  this.Children.Add(new Allitems() {
    Title = "All"
  });
  foreach(var i in objcata) {
    this.Children.Add(new Allitems() {
      Title = i.FilterName
    });
  }
}

// Allitems OnAppearing method below    
protected async override void OnAppearing() {
  base.OnAppearing();
  All.Clear();
  var All1 = await App.TodoManager.GetItemTasksAsync("All");
  foreach(var i in All1) {
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(i.ImageBase64String);
    //I change string to byte
    var newlst = new Catalogcls {
      Name = i.Name,
        UnitPrice = i.UnitPrice + ".00",
        Price = i.Price,
        ImageName = i.ImageName,
        ImageBase64ImageSource = imageBytes,
        Quantity = i.Quantity,
    };
    All.Add(newlst); // We add value to the new list 
  }
  listview.ItemsSource = All;
  GridMethod(); //Here I am calling grid view
}
```

Comment: We have resolve the issue by capturing the session Properties. Application.Current.Properties and we are able to successfully maintain the gridview or listview through out application